# Call cmdlet with array of values (splatting) that includes flag

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am calling the **start-process** command passing an array of values...

```
$args = @{
    FilePath = "c:\myapp.exe"
    RedirectStandardOutput = "c:\output.txt"
};

start-process @args;
```

...this works fine, but I now want to add the **Wait** flag to the arguments for **start-process** but how do you add this to the $args array when it does not need a value assigned to it...

```
$args = @{
    Wait = ?
    FilePath = "c:\myapp.exe"
    RedirectStandardOutput = "c:\output.txt"
};
```

I want to stick with passing the arguments as an array because then they can be passed into a routine which is great for parameterising a process I have.

Comment: Does `-Wait` need to be inside the array or can it proceed after it?

Comment: Can't you just do `Wait = $true`?

Comment: if Wait = $true works then yes, I can certainly do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the best reference but if you look at TechNet for [`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) you will see that the default value for `-Wait` is `False`. This supports that switches or "flags" *can* be treated as booleans.

For you to [splat](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) with the `-Wait` parameter you simply need to provide a boolean value. This is similar to how you would can optionally call a switch in a cmdlet with `-Wait:$true` for example.

```powershell
$args = @{
    Wait = $true
    FilePath = "c:\myapp.exe"
    RedirectStandardOutput = "c:\output.txt"
};
```

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: This is not an answer; rather this is a correction to a point in @Matt's answer but my content cannot fit within the confines of allowable comment formatting.*

While Matt's solution works well for the posed question, there is one inaccuracy: **In general, switches should not be considered "just" Booleans**.

Consider this function:

```
function f([switch]$sw) { "switch is $sw" }
```

And these hashes:

```
$argTrue = @{ sw = $true }
$argFalse = @{ sw = $false }
```

Now review the results:

```
| Call           | Result           | Valid? |
+----------------+------------------+--------+
| f -sw          | switch is True   | Yes    |
| f -sw:$true    | switch is True   | Yes    |
| f -sw:$false   | switch is False  | Yes    |
| f @argTrue     | switch is True   | Yes    |
| f @argFalse    | switch is False  | Yes    |
| f -sw $true    | switch is True   | Yes    |
| f -sw $false   | switch is True   | No!!   |
```

That is treating the switch as "just" an ordinary Boolean parameter, as done in the last two test cases, yields an invalid result for the false case and an accidentally valid result for the true case. But PowerShell is doing what it should be doing: switches do not take arguments, so the $true or $false *or anything* following `-sw` has no bearing whatsoever on the value of the `sw` switch.

In practical terms:

- A Boolean *parameter* is called with `-<paramname> <Boolean value>`
- A Boolean *switch* is called with `-<paramname>:<Boolean value>`

But again, Matt's answer is correct for the posed question, as confirmed by my test cases above. Using splatted arguments **is** treated the same for both a Boolean switch and a Boolean parameter.